# Dictionary to pyspark dataframe with inconsistent columns

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, pyspark

I am currently building a transformation script in pyspark here is the workflow :

- Get raw xml files
- apply XSLT to the raw file which results in another XML containing data for different tables
- Load transformed xml to multiple dataframes
- write dataframes in the lake.

Currently, I am building dictionaries for each row and trying to load them into a row then a dataframe. I am having trouble because every null column does not appear in xml rows. So, some rows will have let's say 20 columns and some 35.

Which leads to

> IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 35 fields are required while 24 values are provided.

Here is how I currently parse my XML to dict to row to Dataframe :

```py
xmlTransformedRoot = xml_transformed.getroot() #XML after xslt being applied
list_of_tables = {child.tag for child in xmlTransformedRoot} #Set to get unique table names
Database = []
for table in list_of_tables:
    listData = []
    for child in xmlTransformedRoot.findall(table):
        data = dict()
        for subelem in child:
            column = subelem.tag.replace("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet}","")
            text = subelem.text
            data[column] = [text]
        listData.append(data)
    Database.append((table,spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in listData)))
```

Would it be possible to load those rows with a function that allows for schemas updates or should I just create the dataframes structure beforehand with the maximum amount of column that could exist ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your data is not valid.  The people who created the schema is requiring certain pieces of data and your xml is missing the important data.  When XML data is created it should be validated by the people who create the xml so the people who use it do not get errors like the ones you are getting.  Contact the people who created the xml and get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by modifying the unpacking line

```
Database.append((table,spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in listData)))
```

to

```
Database.append((table,spark.createDataFrame(listData)))
```

effectively making me insert each dataFrame in one big dictionary.

Apparently psypark can very well handle creating DataFrames from dictionaries even when some fields are missing.